# How to identify newsletters programmatically

Tags: email

Are there any headers in email that help to identify newsletters?
I want to categorize mails as personal, newsletters, spam, and promotions.
Is there any code that can do it?

I want a non-machine learning approach to this question.
Lightweight content analysis will do.

Comment: There's plenty of things code can do. But you'll still need to tell the code how to tell the difference between "spam" and "ham". And if you tell it wrong, it will sort it wrong.

Comment: The solution that I think is the most elegant is the one implemented by [SpamAssassin](https://spamassassin.apache.org). You give it a lot of "spam" and say Bad and then you give it a lot of "ham" and say Good. If you'd like to see how it works, it's open source. Hope that helps.

Comment: I want a non machine learning approach to this question

Comment: You will have to specify that in the question. And, why?

Comment: I want to develop an email client and categorize the I dont want machine learning approach.

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is that almost every client I know of uses a learning approach, because hard filters just don't work. If you insist, you can probably hack together some Regex, but it'll be painful to develop and then only work half the time.

Comment: Instead of voting down ,If more clarity is required on question ,write it in comments

Comment: How can you categorize email without knowing what's in it? There's no standard for what headers you should, even less must, use to identify email content, beyond what's required for mail delivery itself.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't vote it down. I'll let someone else try and help though.

Comment: Content analysis will do but I want a lightweight approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ron Thompson

Comment: I don't think there is a way to distinguish between the slippery slope of "newsletters" vs "promotions" vs "spam".  The only reasonable approximation of a de facto standard is "whatever Google is doing" but that's a moving target, unless you can also copy "have hundreds of millions of users, and actively analyze their behavior".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various headers which can be used to identify mailing lists, but the problem as a whole is somewhat of a heuristic field.  Here are some things to try:

- Common mailing list software packages have their own headers.  Even if they are not explicit, you can rather quickly gather a collection of Majordomo, Listserv, Mailman, Yahoo Groups (bletch) etc. lists and find header patterns which are typical, if not standardized.
- Common and uncommon mailing lists increasingly support the various `List-Xxx:` headers. See further http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/
- Back in the day, many mailing lists would set `Precedence: list`.  Tangentially, see also http://cr.yp.to/immhf.html

Do note that many spammers have adopted some or all of these practices -- pesky mainsleaze spammers tend to use well-established email software just like anybody else in the business; it's just that they are less discriminate about who they add to the mailing list in the first place.

All things counted, I would not dismiss a machine learning approach, if only to help you build a decision tree (not all machine learning is bayesian filtering, you know!)